# Display tooltip on mouseover (load title text from api)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables

I would like to set the title of a cell and retrieve the info from a C# Rest API.
A delay has been added to the example, so the value is only retrieved if the user keeps the mouse for x duration on the cell. This works, however the browser does not immediately display the title once it has been set. I need to jiggle the mouse a little bit to trigger the actual tooltip. Are there any solutions, workarounds and/or better implementations to achieve the described goal. (It is not an option to pre-fill the datatable and set the cell title. It needs to be retrieved adhoc from an api).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris,
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(
            targets = "_all",
            createdCell = JS(
              "function(cell, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex) {",
              "  var timer;",
              "  $(cell).on('mouseover', function() {",
              "    var value = cellData;",
              "    if ($(cell).attr('title') === undefined) {",
              "      timer = setTimeout(function() {",
              "        console.log('Current title:', $(cell).attr('title'));",
              "        $.get('http://localhost:1234/Tooltip?value=' + value, function(data) {",
              "          $(cell).attr('title', data.tooltip);",
              "        });",
              "      }, 500);",
              "    }",
              "  }).on('mouseout', function() {",
              "    clearTimeout(timer);",
              "  });",
              "}"
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```